# How to run a command on an app and get the exit code on cloudfoundry

Tags: python, ssh, cloud-foundry

We need to run arbitrary commands on cloudfoundry. (The deployed apps are Python/Django, but the language for this solution does not matter). Ideally over ssh, but the protocol does not matter.

We need a reliable way to get the exit code of the command that was run, as well as its stderr and stdout. If possible, the command running should be synchronous (as in, blocks the client until the command finished on the cloudfoundry app).

Is there a solution out there that allows us to do this, or what would be a good way to approach this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean get the result **from outside of CloudFoundry** (*i.e.* not one app launching another app and getting result, stdout and stderr).

You can only access CloudFoundry apps over http(s), so you would have to find a way to wrap your invocation into something that exposes everything you need as http.

Comment: It's our own CloudFoundry deployment. Does that help? As in, from somewhere inside CloudFoundry (another app, the server, ...) could we potentially SSH into an app? What about launching a specific second app which runs an SSHd instead of an HTTP service but has the same environment as the web apps?

Comment: Hmm, I guess that opens more possibilities indeed. Now the question boils down to "how do I get hold of (return, stdout, stderr) over **insert your transport here**?" for which I don't think there is a standard answer, sadly :)   I would rather go with some app whose role is to spawn the process, collect result and stdout/stderr and expose that in some way (http would be more in line with what CF does out of the box, but you can come up with others)

Comment: thanks for the info. I think the biggest two issues I see with doing it over http are 1) timeouts and 2) stdin.